# Show the following equality for gradient:

Tags: vector-analysis

My teacher asked to show the following equality:
$$\nabla \cdot \vec{F}(r) = \frac{\vec{r}}{r} \cdot \frac{d\vec{F}}{dr} $$

But for me this equality is not valid. For example: $\vec{F}(r)=\frac{1}{r^2} \widehat{r}$

\begin{align}
  \nabla \cdot \vec{F}(r) &=
  \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} (r^2 \frac{1}{r^2}) \\
  &= \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{d(1)}{d r} \\
  &= 0 \\
\end{align}

And since $F$ depends only on $r$:

$$\frac{\vec{r}}{r} \cdot \frac{d\vec{F}}{dr}=
\frac{\vec{r}}{r} \cdot \frac{d \frac{1}{r^2} \widehat{r}}{dr}$$

Now $\frac{\vec{r}}{r}=\widehat{r}$

\begin{align}
  \frac{\vec{r}}{r} \cdot \frac{d\vec{F}}{dr} &=
  \widehat{r} \cdot \frac{d \frac{1}{r^2}}{dr}\widehat{r} \\
  &= \frac{d \frac{1}{r^2} }{dr} \\
  &= -2\frac{1}{r^3}
\end{align}

So
$$\nabla \cdot \vec{F}(r) \neq \frac{\vec{r}}{r} \cdot \frac{d\vec{F}}{dr}$$

Comment: I don't even know what $\dfrac{d\vec F}{dr}$ is supposed to mean. How do we differentiate $\hat r$ with respect to $r$? And are we supposing that the vector field $\vec F$ is radial in the first place?

Comment: I assumed it was the total derivative and that it was radial. The information I have is only the equation.

Comment: But I thought of the following: $\frac{d \overrightarrow{F}}{dr}=\widehat{r} \frac{dF}{dr}+F\frac{d\widehat{r}}{dr}$. And how $ \frac{d\widehat{r}}{dr}=0$, so $\frac{d \overrightarrow{F}}{dr}=\widehat{r} \frac{dF}{dr}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\vec{F}$ is purely radial, i.e. $\vec{F}(r) = F(r) \hat{r}$,
you have (product rule for divergence)

$$\nabla \cdot \vec{F}(r) = \nabla \cdot F(r)\hat{r} = F(r) \big(\nabla \cdot\hat{r}\big) + \big(\nabla F(r)\big) \cdot \hat{r} $$

Since the divergence of $\hat{r}$ is $\dfrac{2}{r}$, and the gradient of $F(r)$ is $\dfrac{\partial F(r)}{\partial r} \hat{r}$, the equation above simplifies to
$$\nabla \cdot \vec{F}(r) = \dfrac{2F(r)}{r} + \dfrac{\partial F(r)}{\partial r}$$

We can check that for $\vec{F}(r) = \dfrac{1}{r^2}\hat{r}$, both sides now evaluate to $0$.

If in your notation, $\dfrac {\text{d} \vec{F} } {\text{d} r} = \big(\dfrac{2F(r)}{r} + \dfrac{\partial F(r)}{\partial r}\big) \hat{r}$, then everything checks out.

Comment: But should not d(**F**)/dr be a total derivative?

Comment: Like @tedshifrin commented, that doesn't really make sense.  How do you define the derivative of a vector valued function with respect to a scalar? (Note this notation is conventional in the context of material derivatives, but i don't think that's relevant here). In your example above, you approach this by differentiating the scalar coefficient of a unit vector, i.e. taking $\dfrac{d\vec{F}(r)}{dr} = \dfrac{dF(r)}{dr} \hat{r}$, but that probably isn't the right interpretation of the notation, since it produced an invalid result.  Similarly, treating it as a directional derivative is unhelpful

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, that's what I thought. I'm going to ask what my teacher's interpretation is.

Comment: Like I said for @tedshifrin, I thought that: $\frac{d \overrightarrow{F}}{dr}=\widehat{r} \frac{dF}{dr}+F\frac{d\widehat{r}}{dr}$, and how $ \frac{d\widehat{r}}{dr}=0$, so $\frac{d \overrightarrow{F}}{dr}=\widehat{r} \frac{dF}{dr}$